# Want to highlight/change color of certain words in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I am setting text using the following:

```
var someString = 'Mark has solved the problem';
editor.getSession().setValue(someString);
```

In above case, Need only 'Mark' to appear in blue color.
Is there a way to load html tags in ace editor or manipulate styling of certain words?

Answer (score 7):

You can create custom highlight rules to do this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .ace_customTokenName {color: darkred}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="editor" style="height: 500px; width: 800px"></div>
    
<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
<script>
define('ace/mode/custom', [], function(require, exports, module) {
var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
var Tokenizer = require("ace/tokenizer").Tokenizer;
var CustomHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules").CustomHighlightRules;

var Mode = function() {
    this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;
};
oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

(function() {

}).call(Mode.prototype);

exports.Mode = Mode;
});

define('ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules', [], function(require, exports, module) {
var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var CustomHighlightRules = function() {

    var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
        "variable.language": "this",
        "keyword": "Mark|Ben|Bill",
        "constant.language": "true|false|null",
        // it is also possible to use css, but that may conflict with themes
        "customTokenName": "problem"
    }, "text", true);

    this.$rules = {
        "start": [            
            {
                regex: "\\w+\\b",
                token: keywordMapper
            },
        ]
    };
    this.normalizeRules()
};

oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.CustomHighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;
});


var editor = ace.edit("editor");

editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/custom");
var someString = 'Mark has solved the problem';
editor.session.setValue(someString);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it replace the existing tokens of the supported language mode or append to existing tokens? If we have to add more words to the predefined mode dynamically and remove it dynamically like for mode python add more keywords, is there any way to do this?

Comment: It would be great for the example if you could return a token name that is a custom name and then provide a CSS class with the "ace_" prefix and that custom name. For example returning "danger" as a token in the keywordMapper, and then defining the CSS class "ace_danger" in which you would set the "color" property to "red". I was looking for this myself for some time, so it is non-obvious. Also, it would better answer the question I think.