# Ace editor coloring words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I'm trying to colorize some specific words in the Ace editor (for example I want the word 'Hello' to be colored in red).
I tried working with their 'highlight rules' (https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter) but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm working with react and javascript by the way.

Can anyone suggest a solution or example?

Answer (score 6):

Ace doesn't provide this feature by default, but you can using 'custom highlight rules' in ace editor.

I know that they have released this feature for customizing various new languages.

Ref:

https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/highlighting-rules

Related Stack Answer:

[Want to highlight/change color of certain words in Ace Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735711/want-to-highlight-change-color-of-certain-words-in-ace-editor)

Comment: I'd seen this one before and was hoping there was a better method available. Do you know how to copy rich text from the editor and paste it to microsoft word with the colors intact? Using the highlighting rules method you described doesn't seem to allow this?

Comment: @Shiva, oh, here is the Shiva! Hare-hare Mahadev! But why this is the wiki answer I do not understand.