# Highlight word in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, ace-editor, react-ace

I'm using Ace Editor and specifically `react-ace`. I want to highlight a certain word.

I am aware that I can define custom syntax highlighting rules but it seems more hassle than it's worth compared to updating a marker every time the input changes (which in my case, should not be too often).

For a marker, I need the `Range` of the word - `startRow`, `startCol`, `endRow`, `endCol`.
I tried using `find()` for this, and it seems to indeed return the desired range of a term/regex I search for, but this seems to a high-level command which performs what you would expect from a "find" operation in an editor - highlights the term and *jumps* to it.

How would I go about retrieving the `Range` of a word in an Ace Editor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735711/want-to-highlight-change-color-of-certain-words-in-ace-editor Possible duplicate, but this should be it.

Comment: @alexholstv This is what I referred to as the custom syntax highlighting which I know can be done, but I would rather avoid it. I am also not sure on how to _extend_ an existing Ace mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undocumented `preventScroll` option to find that returns the range [ace/editor.js#L2593-L2594](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/520c6489354cd36d2a3af5ae93414268f4ecc0e8/lib/ace/editor.js#L2593-L2594), and you can also use the `$search` directly to find all ranges similar to [ace/multi_select.js#L568](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/520c6489354cd36d2a3af5ae93414268f4ecc0e8/lib/ace/multi_select.js#L568). It's worth noting that this would not be the most efficient and performant method to highlight large number of ranges, but that depends on specific details of the problem you are trying to solve which are not stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I needed :)