# Highlighting in ACE editor that is embedded in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, highlight, ace-editor

I try to highlight a set of words in the ace-editor that is embedded in an R Shiny app. I followed suggestions from [Want to highlight/change color of certain words in Ace Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735711/want-to-highlight-change-color-of-certain-words-in-ace-editor), but highlighting does not work when the `aceEditor()` function is used, which I need for my app. However, if I replace the `aceEditor()` function with a tags$body command (see below), highlighting works. Please see my code below. My question: Is there a way to use highlighting with the `aceEditor()` function?

Here is an example in which the word Mark should appear in blue.

Use of `aceEditor()`, which fails:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

htmlScript = "<script>\n define('ace/mode/custom', [], function(require, exports, module) {\n var oop = require(\"ace/lib/oop\");\n var TextMode = require(\"ace/mode/text\").Mode;"
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n var Tokenizer = require(\"ace/tokenizer\").Tokenizer;\n var CustomHighlightRules = require(\"ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules\").CustomHighlightRules;")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n\n var Mode = function() {\n this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;\n};\n oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);\n\n (function() {\n\n}).call(Mode.prototype);\n\n exports.Mode = Mode;\n});")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n define('ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules', [], function(require, exports, module) {\n var oop = require(\"ace/lib/oop\");\n var TextHighlightRules = require(\"ace/mode/text_highlight_rules\").TextHighlightRules;\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n var CustomHighlightRules = function() {\n\n var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({\n \"variable.language\": \"this\",\n \"keyword\": \"Mark|Ben|Bill\",\n \"constant.language\": \"true|false|null\",\n \"customTokenName\": \"problem\"\n}, \"text\", true);\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n this.$rules = {\n\"start\": [\n{\nregex: \"\\\\w+\\\\b\",\n token: keywordMapper\n},\n]\n};\n this.normalizeRules()\n};\n\n oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);\n\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\nexports.CustomHighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;\n});\n\nvar editor = ace.edit(\"editor\");\n\n editor.session.setMode(\"ace/mode/custom\");\n</script>")
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(HTML("<script src=\"https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js\"></script>")),

  aceEditor("editor", value="Mark", mode = "text"), #Mark should be highlighted with blue color

  tags$body(HTML(htmlScript))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Use of `tags$body` command, which works:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(HTML("<script src=\"https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js\"></script>")),

  tags$body(HTML("<div id=\"editor\" style=\"height: 500px; width: 800px\"></div>")),

  tags$body(HTML(htmlScript))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please type the word Mark in the editor, it will appear in blue.

Answer (score 1):

`shinyAce` wraps the calls to the `ace` libraries. In particular the `mode` which defines the syntax highlighting. I am not an expert in `JavaScript`, hence, I do not know where and how `aceEditor` overrules your manual settings, but I know enough to know how you could get your custom style working.

1. Create a `.js` file with the following content:

   ```
   ace.define('ace/mode/custom', [], function(require, exports, module) {
      var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
      var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
      var Tokenizer = require("ace/tokenizer").Tokenizer;
      var CustomHighlightRules = 
      require("ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules").CustomHighlightRules;

      var Mode = function() {
           this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;
      };
      oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);
      (function() {
      }).call(Mode.prototype);
      exports.Mode = Mode;
   });

   ace.define('ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules', [], function(require, exports, module) {
      var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
      var TextHighlightRules = 
      require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

      var CustomHighlightRules = function() {

          var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
              "variable.language": "this",
              "keyword": "Mark|Ben|Bill",
              "constant.language": "true|false|null",
              "customTokenName": "problem"
          }, "text", true);

          this.$rules = {
              "start": [{
                  regex: "\\w+\\b",
                  token: keywordMapper
              }, ]
          };
          this.normalizeRules()
      };

      oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);
      exports.CustomHighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;
   });
   ```

   Note in particular the use of `ace.define` instead of `define`.
2. Place the file in the folder shown by

   ```r
   system.file("www/ace", package = "shinyAce")
   ```

   under the name `mode-custom.js`.
3. Then you are set and the following code highlights `Mark` correctly:

   ```r
   library(shiny)
   library(shinyAce)
   ui <- fluidPage(
      aceEditor("editor", value = "Mark", mode = "custom") 
   )

   server <- function(input, output, session){}
   shinyApp(ui, server)
   ```

   [image: Custom Syntax Highlighting]

---

### Update

Actually you do not need to store the `js` in the lib folder, but define it on the spot. Just make suere that you use `ace.define` nad you use the name of the mode in `aceEditor`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)

htmlScript = "<script>\n ace.define('ace/mode/custom', [], function(require, exports, module) {\n var oop = require(\"ace/lib/oop\");\n var TextMode = require(\"ace/mode/text\").Mode;"
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n var Tokenizer = require(\"ace/tokenizer\").Tokenizer;\n var CustomHighlightRules = require(\"ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules\").CustomHighlightRules;")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n\n var Mode = function() {\n this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;\n};\n oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);\n\n (function() {\n\n}).call(Mode.prototype);\n\n exports.Mode = Mode;\n});")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n ace.define('ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules', [], function(require, exports, module) {\n var oop = require(\"ace/lib/oop\");\n var TextHighlightRules = require(\"ace/mode/text_highlight_rules\").TextHighlightRules;\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n var CustomHighlightRules = function() {\n\n var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({\n \"variable.language\": \"this\",\n \"keyword\": \"Mark|Ben|Bill|Thorn|ULL\",\n \"constant.language\": \"true|false|null\",\n \"customTokenName\": \"problem\"\n}, \"text\", true);\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\n this.$rules = {\n\"start\": [\n{\nregex: \"\\\\w+\\\\b\",\n token: keywordMapper\n},\n]\n};\n this.normalizeRules()\n};\n\n oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);\n\n")
htmlScript = paste0(htmlScript,"\nexports.CustomHighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules;\n});\n\nvar editor = ace.edit(\"editor\");\n\n editor.session.setMode(\"ace/mode/custom\");\n</script>")
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  aceEditor("editor", value="Mark", mode = "custom"), #Mark should be highlighted with blue color
  tags$body(HTML(htmlScript))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
``
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I may add: It is important to change mode to "custom". I had "text" in my version, which does not work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I said: "you use the name of the mode in aceEditor". - if it helps please accept the answer.