# Highlighting words with unicode characters (accents, etc) in Ace Editor

Tags: regex, unicode, highlight, ace-editor, non-ascii-characters

I need to hightlight specific keywords of pseudocode into Ace Editor. I've found at the below post a nice and simple solution that works fine:

[Want to highlight/change color of certain words in Ace Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735711/want-to-highlight-change-color-of-certain-words-in-ace-editor)

But unfortunately, it works only with words composed of ASCII characters, and not non-ascii extended unicode characters such as accentuated characters like the french ones: éêàâ and so on.

So I've modified the regex used to parse and find words in code `regex: "\\w+\\b"`

with this one:

```
    this.$rules = {
        "start": [            
            {
                regex: "[\u{0}-\u{10FFFF}]+\\b",
                token: keywordMapper
            },
        ]
    };
    this.normalizeRules()
```

And now it works fine, accepting keywords like 'r**é**p**é**ter' (repeat) or 'derri**è**re' (backwards), containing accentuated characters. BUT it doesn't recognize words terminated with an accent, like for instance 'jusqu**à**' (until) or 'modifi**é**' (modified), when the accentuated letter is the last one of the word. Any idea? Thanks a lot for your precious help!

Laurent

PS: same problem with alternative `regex: ".+\\b"`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution. The regular expression of the rule used to highlight words needs to be followed with a **/u** flag. But the 'regex' attribute of the rule cannot contain a flag at its ends.

Ace Editor adds the **/g** flag before executing a regular expression (/g for global, in order to process all meeting occurences corresponding to the regex, not just stopping to the first one).

If we need to ask Ace to add the **/u** flag (ordering the regular epxression to be processed including *unicode* characters), we have to add an **'unicode'** attribute to the rule and the value of this attribute must be **true**.

Then, if we want to select each word composed of Unicode latin letters and digits, we can use for instance the below regex :

```
[\\p{Script_Extensions=Latin}0-9]+
```

(note the escape character \ is doubled into 'regex' attrbute value)

Finally, it gives this adaptated solution (from the upper quoted post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735711/want-to-highlight-change-color-of-certain-words-in-ace-editor][1]):

```
define('ace/mode/pseudo', [], function(require, exports, module) { var oop = require("ace/lib/oop"); var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode; var Tokenizer = require("ace/tokenizer").Tokenizer; var CustomHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules").CustomHighlightRules; var identifierRe = "[a-zA-Z\\$_\u00a1-\uffff][a-zA-Z\\d\\$_\u00a1-\uffff]*";
     var Mode = function() {
    this.HighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules; }; oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

(function() {

}).call(Mode.prototype);

exports.Mode = Mode; });

define('ace/mode/custom_highlight_rules', [], function(require, exports, module) { var oop = require("ace/lib/oop"); var TextHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var CustomHighlightRules = function() {

    var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
        "variable.language": "this",
        "keyword": "avancer|sauter|tourner|jusquà|répéter|fois|si",
        "constant.language": "devant|à|derrière|gauche|droite|crevasse|glacier|trace|paroie|123",
        "customTokenName": "problem"
    }, "text", true);

    this.$rules = {
        
        "start": [            
            {
                regex: "[\\p{Script_Extensions=Latin}0-9]+",
                token: keywordMapper,
                unicode: true
            },
        ]
    };
    this.normalizeRules() };

oop.inherits(CustomHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.CustomHighlightRules = CustomHighlightRules; });
```

Comment: An alternative would be to pass a function to `token` or `onMatch` to perform any additional validation yourself there, picking either your desired token type or `"text"`.